# How to ensure that a custom function runs after execution of every Python Unittest?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I want to ensure that a custom function runs after each test.

Right now, I have the following solution that involves adding a `tearDown()` call in each unitTest module which seems to be an overkill.

```
import unittest

custom_descr = []


def do_something(test):
    custom_descr.append('from '.format(test))


class Tester(unittest.TestCase):
   def test_1(self):
       do_something('test_1')

    def tearDown(self):
        for descr in custom_descr:
            print(descr)
```

Is it possible to avoid a writing the `tearDown()` in each module by centralizing any description in any base_class as per the idea below **(following does not work though)**:

```
import unittest

# in common_module.py
custom_descr = []


def do_something(test):
    custom_descr.append('from '.format(test))

class Test_Base(unittest.TestCase):           
    def tearDown(self):
        for descr in custom_descr:
            print(descr)

# in module1.py
class Tester1(Test_Base):
   def test_1(self):
       do_something('test_1')

# in module2.py
class Tester2(Test_Base):
   def test_2(self):
       do_something('test_2')
```

Comment: I think you answered your question correctly

Comment: @Pynchia - but the above solution does not work. Base Class tearDown is not called after a test. Only its own tearDown is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple solution is to add `self.tearDown = Test_Base.warn` in the setup of each test module but it is far from what I desire - because I still need to repeat the code (however small) in each module

```
import unittest

// in common_module.py
custom_descr = []


def do_something(test):
    custom_descr.append('from '.format(test))

class Test_Base(unittest.TestCase):           
    def final(self):
        for descr in custom_descr:
            print(descr)

//in module1.py
class Tester1(Test_Base):
  def setUp(self):
       self.tearDown = Test_Base.final

   def test_1(self):
       do_something('test_1')

//in module2.py
class Tester2(Test_Base):
    def setUp(self):
       self.tearDown = Test_Base.final

   def test_2(self):
       do_something('test_2')
```